# There is an error in my C# program that occur a stack overflow Exception

Tags: c#

i have 2 forms. one of them is a form that User select a school class so click OK. I use

> > public int[] grad_class=new int[2];

for save which School class has selected. (list of classes is COMBO BOX)
after that i open another new form to edit information of that class' students.
i use Switch like this:

```
switch(grad_class)
{
   case "11": something to do..., break;
   case "12": something to do..., break;
}
```

But My problem :
I define "grad_class" in form No.1 . so when i want to use that i have to do this:

```
form1 f1 = new form1();
f1.grade_class;
```

and in form No.2 i call this code.
in form No.1 i call:

```
form2 f2 = new form2();
```

OCCUR STACK OVERFLOW EXCEPTION !!!

Comment: What does the constructor of form2 look like?

Comment: Show code for form2 constructor.

Comment: A question about a stack overflow on StackOverflow? I think I've just stack-overflowed myself.

Comment: You obviously have an issue in the constructor for `form2`. You also have a serious design issue that makes it hard to reason about your program. Read about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

```
form1 f1 = new form1();
f1.grade_class;
```

> and in form No.2 i call this code. in form No.1 i call:

```
form2 f2 = new form2();
```

Well, there's your issue right there. You state that in `form1` you call `form2.ctor` and in `form2` you call `form1.ctor`. So your code looks like this:

```
public form1() {
    var f2 = new form2();
}

public form2() {
    var f1 = new form1();
}
```

Well, of course this results in a stack overflow. These are mutally recursive functions. You have no return condition, so you exhaust your stack space. Quite simply, what is happening is that the machine has to store state about where to go next when a method is finished. It typically stores this information in space called the stack. The stack is bounded though, so if you push too many "this is where to go next" blocks onto the stack by repeatedly invoking methods, you will exhaust this stack space and hit the infamous stack overflow exception.

Edit: You said:

```
namespace TeacherBook {
    public partial class ChooseGrade : Form {
        public int[] grad_class=new int[2]; //int array for grade & class (first for Grade,second for class) 
        EditStudent StdForm = new EditStudent();
    }
namespace TeacherBook {
    public partial class EditStudent : Form {
        ChooseGrade ChGrade = new ChooseGrade(); // define form 
    }
}
```

Effectively what I suspected. You have a field initializer in `ChooseGrade` that instantiates a new instance of `EditStudent`. But `EditStudent` has a field initializer that instantiates a new instance of `ChooseGrade`. So when you instantiate a new instance of `ChooseGrade`, this causes the constructor for `EditStudent` to be invoked, which causes the constructor for `ChooseGrade` to be invoked, which causes the constructor for `EditStudent` to be invoked, and on and on it goes until you overflow your stack.

Comment: Help us help you. What are you confused by?

Comment: Well, that's not really telling me what you're confused by, but fine I'll play along. Eliminate the mutual recursion. It doesn't make sense for these forms to mutually include each other.